# Detectron2 - How to use RepeatFactorTrainingSampler in class imbalance problem

Tags: imbalanced-data, detectron

I'm facing class imbalance problem in a 2 classes classification problem.

Generally class 1 is about 25% of class 2. (class 1= 100 observations, class 2 = 400)

So i will need class 1 to have 4x times more than the current observation.

With the current setting:

```
cfg.DATALOADER.SAMPLER_TRAIN = "RepeatFactorTrainingSampler"
cfg.DATALOADER.REPEAT_THRESHOLD = 2
```

`cfg.DATALOADER.REPEAT_THRESHOLD` is a threshold for both classes? How can i increase the sample for class 1 only?

Thank you.